# mysql 7 + joins on a table, how to speed up?

Tags: mysql, join

I have 7 tables. Table 1 is the 'parent table' and `has_many` relationships with tables 2-7.

I'd like to make a query that grabs the rows of table 1, with a list of the ids from table 2-7. I've tried the below query but with a large database my query takes 15 seconds. I'm wondering how I can make this query faster?

**Edit** A couple of notes:
-> Removing Distinct only saves 4 seconds and I still get a query of 10-11 seconds

-> Removing 1 join table (doesn't matter which) from the query reduces the time from 15 seconds to 2-3 seconds. Removing 2 join tables (again doesn't matter which) reduces the query to 1/2 second.

```
SELECT  
  table1.table1_id as table1Id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table2.table2_id) AS table2Ids,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table3.table3_id) AS table3Ids,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table4.table4_id) AS table4Ids,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table5.table5_id) AS table5Ids,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table6.table6_id) AS table6Ids,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table7.table7_id) AS table7Ids
  FROM table1
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.table1_id = table2.table1_id
  LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.table1_id = table3.table1_id
  LEFT JOIN table4 ON table1.table1_id = table4.table1_id
  LEFT JOIN table5 ON table1.table1_id = table5.table1_id
  LEFT JOIN table6 ON table1.table1_id = table6.table1_id
  LEFT JOIN table7 ON table1.table1_id = table7.table1_id
  WHERE table1.archived = false
  GROUP BY table1.table1_id LIMIT 1000
```

My explain query:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                                                                      | key                       | key_len | ref                      | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1           | NULL       | index | PRIMARY,unique_name_in_table8, table8_idx,table9_idx,table10_idx                                   | PRIMARY                   | 4       | NULL                     |    1 |    10.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table2           | NULL       | ref   | PRIMARY                                                                                            | PRIMARY                   | 4       | db.table1.table1_id      |   20 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table3           | NULL       | ref   | table3_to_table1_id_idx                                                                            | table3_to_table1_id_idx   | 4       | db.table1.table1_id      |  824 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table4           | NULL       | ref   | table4_word_unique,table4_to_table1_id_idx                                                         | table4_to_table1_id_idx   | 4       | db.table1.table1_id      |    4 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table5           | NULL       | ref   | table5_to_table1_id_idx                                                                            | table5_to_table1_id_idx   | 4       | db.table1.table1_id      |   26 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table6           | NULL       | ref   | table6_to_table1_id_idx                                                                            | table6_to_table1_id_idx   | 4       | db.table1.table1_id      |    3 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table7           | NULL       | ref   | table7_to_table1_id_idx                                                                            | table7_to_table1_id_idx   | 4       | db.table1.table1_id      |  483 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Is it possible to eliminate `distinct` ? AFAIK, it causes burden at backend.

Comment: @PrabhatG I've added a comment. Eliminating distinct only saves 4 seconds, and I'd rather not have duplicates. Is there a more efficient way to run this query?

Comment: can you join this [chat] (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146828/chat-for-mysql-7-joins-on-a-table-how-to-speed-up)

Comment: Perhaps add the table#_ID to the index such that table1_ID, table#_ID is a composite index.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to rewrite the query. Try and let me know. I haven't tested it.

```
SELECT  
  t1.table1Id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table2.table2_id) AS table2Ids,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table3.table3_id) AS table3Ids,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table4.table4_id) AS table4Ids,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table5.table5_id) AS table5Ids,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table6.table6_id) AS table6Ids,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table7.table7_id) AS table7Ids
FROM (
    SELECT table1_id as table1Id
    FROM table1
    WHERE table1.archived = false
    GROUP BY table1.table1_id LIMIT 1000
      ) AS t1
  INNER JOIN table2 ON t1.table1Id = table2.table1_id
  INNER JOIN table3 ON t1.table1Id = table3.table1_id
  INNER JOIN table4 ON t1.table1Id = table4.table1_id
  INNER JOIN table5 ON t1.table1Id = table5.table1_id
  INNER JOIN table6 ON t1.table1Id = table6.table1_id
  INNER JOIN table7 ON t1.table1Id = table7.table1_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The explain says that `table2` doesn't have an index on `table1Id`.

Try:

```
create index table2_to_table1_id_idx on table2(table1Id);
```

That might improve the performance enough, but to maximize performance for this particular query create *covering* indexes:

```
 create index table2_table1_id_idx on table2(table1Id, table2Id);
 create index table3_table1_id_idx on table3(table1Id, table3Id);
 create index table4_table1_id_idx on table4(table1Id, table4Id);
 create index table5_table1_id_idx on table5(table1Id, table5Id);
 create index table6_table1_id_idx on table6(table1Id, table6Id);
 create index table7_table1_id_idx on table7(table1Id, table7Id);
```

Having these indexes means you can avoid hitting the base tables entirely.

Comment: Learner's curiosity. Can you explain points of your answer ? How did you determine if index is not there through `explain`. How covering index will avoid hitting base tables entirely ?